# why mips is called load/store architecture?

Tags: architecture

i am studying my high school computer architecture course where i learn MIPS for understanding pipe lining!  so can you guys please help me figuring out this puzzle , thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIPS is called load/store architecture because the instructions available in mips to interact with memory are only load and store.
lw for loading data from mem to reg and sw to store the data from reg to memory.

Comment: so you are proposing that we have load and store instruction to intreact with memory in MIPS ??

Comment: Yes.. we dont have any other instruction in mips to interact with memory except load and store.However,different variants of lw and sw are available like lb(load byte),etc